# Gradients and Laplacian of an image using skimage vs. open-cv

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib, scikit-image, laplacian

I compare the vertical and horizontal gradients and Laplacian of an image using skimage and cv2 with the following code:

```
import sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.image import imread
import skimage
import cv2

def plot(ax, img, title):
    ax.imshow(img) # cmap = 'gray'
    ax.set_title(title)
    ax.set_xticks([])
    ax.set_yticks([])

img = imread("./strawberry.jpg")
laplacian = cv2.Laplacian(img,cv2.CV_32F)
sobelx = cv2.Sobel(img,cv2.CV_32F,1,0,ksize=3)
sobely = cv2.Sobel(img,cv2.CV_32F,0,1,ksize=3)

fig1 = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
fig1.suptitle('cv2', fontsize=14, fontweight='bold')
ax = fig1.add_subplot(221)
plot(ax, img, 'Original')
ax = fig1.add_subplot(222)
plot(ax, laplacian, 'Laplacian')
ax = fig1.add_subplot(223)
plot(ax, sobelx, 'Sobel X')
ax = fig1.add_subplot(224)
plot(ax, sobely, 'Sobel Y')
fig1.set_tight_layout(True)

laplacian = skimage.filters.laplace(img,ksize=5)
sobelx = skimage.filters.sobel(img, axis=0)
sobely = skimage.filters.sobel(img, axis=1)

fig2 = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
fig2.suptitle('skimage', fontsize=14, fontweight='bold')
ax = fig2.add_subplot(221)
plot(ax, img, 'Original')
ax = fig2.add_subplot(222)
plot(ax, laplacian, 'Laplacian')
ax = fig2.add_subplot(223)
plot(ax, sobelx, 'Sobel X')
ax = fig2.add_subplot(224)
plot(ax, sobely, 'Sobel Y')
fig2.set_tight_layout(True)

plt.show()
```

Here are the results:

[image]

[image]

So, they are vastly different. Even if the kernels would differ, I would not expect such differences. Did I miss something in my script ?

Comment: matplotlib issue. figure out the data types and value ranges of the things you plot.

Comment: Indeed, data types play a role. cv2 seems to internally promote img from uint8 to float32 whereas skimage does not, I have to do it manually, i.e. with img = img.astype(float) for skimage, I get for the gradients approximately the same pictures. Curiously, if I cast the pixel values into float for cv2, cv2 refuses to compute the gradients and laplacian.

Comment: what you call "internal promotion" happens because you pass `CV_32F` for the result type parameter. both the laplacian and sobel functions should accept single floats. I don't know off the top of my head if they'll accept double floats. an actual refusal would result in a failed assertion and a traceback.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with the code I posted.

First, the Laplace filter from skimage works only with gray-scale images but not with color images. For the adaptation, I followed [Adapting gray-scale filters to RGB images](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/auto_examples/color_exposure/plot_adapt_rgb.html), so we should have

```
from skimage.color.adapt_rgb import adapt_rgb, each_channel

@adapt_rgb(each_channel)
def skimage_filters_laplace(img, ksize):
    return skimage.filters.laplace(img, ksize)
```

and then

```
laplacian = skimage_filters_laplace(img,ksize=3)
```

Second, there is a scaling problem; if I properly rescale the output of cv2 into [0,1], then it is fine. The examples with `cv2.Sobel()` I found use `cv2.imshow()`, it seems that the use of matplotlib to render images analyzed with cv2 makes trouble.